# vim indentation level next to number line

Tags: vim, indentation

I have installed the indentLine plugin for vim. I'm trying to print the number of tabs for each line but I didn't find a solution. As examples, there are these pictures

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/N84RM.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e15N.jpg

I'm talking about the pink and blue numbers (and the '|' and '-' chars) on the pictures.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are not directly related to your indentation: rather they are part of the informations displayed by the "fold column". Add the following command to your `vimrc` to enable a 1 character-wide column like in those screenshot:

```
set foldcolumn=1
```

See `:help folding`.